# What books and/or resources are available to learn Puzzle Design?

Tags: puzzle-creation

Is there any literature that goes into detail about ideas and best practices for designing puzzles?

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling Stack Exchange! Apologies about the confusion over migration. It looks like this question as written may be too broad for us to answer, though. Could you edit to narrow the scope of possible answers? For instance, you could specify which types of puzzles you're looking to create. Thank you!

Comment: I would say it is too broad if there would be too many answers. As it stands, the question is still waiting for a *single* answer! (I, for one, would be very interested in some answrers here myself.)

Comment: I've answered this question here: http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/3026/what-books-and-or-resources-are-available-to-learn-puzzle-design. If you want my answer to be moved to this thread, just ask.

Comment: @leoll2 Moving your answer would be a good idea. The question on meta has been put on hold for being off topic there.

Comment: Personally, I'm stunned that this is off-topic. Wow

Comment: Swinging the close hammer because this is a "big list" question,  which are generally off-topic across the Stack Exchange network (see meta.SE posts http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/158809/180276 and http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/98334/180276).